# Using Eonasdan Link DateTime Picker Restrict User to select date between a Month only

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

i am Using Eonasdan Link DateTime Picker and did not any idea how to restrict user to select date between one month ..(One month from selected date of first DateTimePicker i.e StartDate).

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                  <div class='input-group date' id="FuelLogStartDate">
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="FuelLogStartDate" value="@Model.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class='input-group date' id="FuelLogEndDate">
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="FuelLogEndDate" value="@Model.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {    

        $('#FuelLogStartDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
        });
        $('#FuelLogEndDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            useCurrent: false 
        });
        $("#FuelLogStartDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#FuelLogEndDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#FuelLogEndDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#FuelLogStartDate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines to set the min date & max dates(while initializing the picker in JS) for the datetime picker.

```
minDate: moment("2016-01-01T01:00:01-04:00"),
maxDate: moment("2016-01-31T01:00:01-04:00")
```